# Vpnc script bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, vpn

I use vpnc in terminal to setup a vpn connection, is there a way that i can make a script so when i execute the script it just starts. Instead of putting again al the gateway info etc.

Answer (score 0):

From `man vpnc`:

```
CONFIGURATION
       The daemon reads configuration data from the following places:
       ·      command line options
       ·      config file(s) specified on the command line
       ·      /etc/vpnc/default.conf
       ·      /etc/vpnc.conf
       ·      prompting the user if not found above
```

You probably either want to modify the `/etc/vpnc/default.conf` or create a new one such as `/etc/vpnc/myvpn.conf` so you can type either (probably with sudo) `vpnc` or `vpnc myvpn`